# iPhone UIDatePicker Gradient - What are the colors?

Tags: iphone, gradient, uidatepicker

I'm putting in a UIDatePicker in a UIView and I can see that the UIDatePicker has a border that is some kind of a dark color on the bottom and it gets lighter as you get higher.  I want the containing UIView to use the same colors so that the UIDatePicker flows with the rest of the view and doesn't stand out.

I can put in a gradient in the containing view, but I don't know what colors to use! If anyone could suggest them, I'd appreciate it.

```
     mj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light Color (Top): RGB: 145,146,154

Dark Color (Bottom): RGB: 30,31,44

Use Digital Color Meter that is built-in to OS X (in the Utilities folder).

Answer (score 1):

The colours displayed in Xcode don't always match those when the app is viewed on an actual iOS device, especially for UIDatePicker object.

What I've found useful is the following:

1. Run the app on an iOS device with your objects on screen
2. Take a screenshot (hold down the home button and the power button together)
3. Email that screenshot to your Mac
4. Use the OS X Digital Color Meter on the screenshot to get accurate RGB values

Remember to check both retina and non retina devices for colour matching.